# im learning about files and excptions in the python crash course book. cant figure out why its saying votes = judge.read() has no attribute to write

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
 print("\nEnter 'q' if you want to end poll.")
while True: 
    person = input('What is your name? ')
    answers = input('what do you like most about programming? ')
    print(person + ", your answer have been stored. Thanks for input.")
if person == 'q':
    break
pollss = 'poll_record.txt'
with open(pollss,'r+') as judge:
    votes = judge.read()
    votes.write(person)
    votes.write('\nAnswer was ' + answers)
    votes.write('\n')
booth = ''
for counts in votes:
   booth+=votes
```

im new to python so i understand if its a easier way to write this code but i will learn that later this how i understand how to write it now. but any construtive criticism will be helpful thank you.

Comment: also noticed i did the for loop wrong so dont mind that

Comment: you need to align the code well, plus to write you need to do that on the file object not on the list object ie use write with the judge not with the votes

Comment: yes sorry about that seen that at the if statement  @sahaseara62 your right thank you so much.

Comment: Also, that 's an amazing book, I love it, and I'm still reading the end.

Comment: @oakenduck yes it a amazing book i would definitely recommend it to any beginner.

Answer (score 1):

Just change this three line

```
judge.write(person)
judge.write('\nAnswer was ' + answers)
judge.write('\n')
```

because you want to write in that file.

Comment: If it's your answer then please mark it as Accepted answer

Comment: well all of the are the same answer.does it help your profile if i vote this as my answer>

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is because in `votes = judge.read()` you are assigning the content inside `judge` to variable `votes`, and it is interpreted as a string. `votes` is not a file, just a string, so it doesn't have the attributes that a file does, which is why when you try to `write()` to that string, it returns an error. You should instead write to the file:

```py
with open(polls, 'r+') as judge:
    judge.write(person)
    judge.write('\nAnswer was', answers, '\n')
```

This should solve the problem.

Comment: thank you for the help . i should have just looked at what i did in the previous exercise 10-4 guest book. but i been at it all day probably  need a break for tonight.lol